# Is there a way to automate extraction of "page source" HTML/json data?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying pull down price and quantity data from a [Chiefs game on ticketmaster](https://www.ticketmaster.com/kansas-city-chiefs-vs-las-vegas-kansas-city-missouri-10-11-2020/event/060058FEB7590E10) to see how quantities have changed with COVID but there's no easy way to get the data off the screen (API not an option since I need seat/row breakout).

I tried using puppeteer and a headless browser (code below) but was blocked by the site (they recognized it's a bot). I stumbled across the option to right click and "view page source" and [can see everything in json](http://view-source:https://www.ticketmaster.com/kansas-city-chiefs-vs-las-vegas-kansas-city-missouri-10-11-2020/event/060058FEB7590E10) -- which is great because I can parse this into some structured format.

I'd like to get some more of this data with regularity and without the ability to pull by linking into the html through puppeteer, would pulling from the "page source" be my best option? And is there a way I could automate a copy/paste from the "page source" if puppeteer is already blocked?

I'm relatively new with javascript so any help would be appreciated!!

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function getTix(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const url = 'https://www.ticketmaster.com/kansas-city-chiefs-vs-las-vegas-kansas-city-missouri-10-11-2020/event/060058FEB7590E10';

    await page.goto(url);

    await page.waitForSelector(".quick-picks__list-item");

    const results = await page.$$eval(".quick-picks__list-item", rows => {
        return rows.map(row => {
            const properties = {};
            const titleElement = row.querySelector(".result-title");
            properties.title = titleElement.innerText;
            return properties;
        });
    })

    console.log(results);

}

getTix();
```

Comment: A few things: Scraping Ticketmaster pages like this is probably against their Terms of Use and publishing the results likely has ethical and legal ramifications. Ticketmaster is probably rejecting your request because of the User-Agent. (Puppeteer likely provides a way to change that.) You don't need specifically Puppeteer if you just want original, non-parsed page source. JSON and Javascript objects can look very similar but are not the same thing.

Comment: Hi @ouroborus - I wouldn't be publishing anything, just running analysis for a group project. I've been counting them manually and was just looking for a way to simplify for the next week. What do you mean by JSON and Javascript objects looking similar but being different?

Comment: You can read more about JSON on [their website](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). Basically, it's just a way to store data in a string. The distinction may not matter in your application. The syntax between Javascript and JSON has enough overlap that you can often treat data that's JSON-encoded as though it were Javascript. (This is what they're doing when they generate that page you're looking at.)